# Scrollbar not working in cordova

Tags: android, html, css, angularjs, cordova

I am a long time struggling with my Angular application / Cordova, I'm having the following problem, the desktop scrolling bar appears normally and works normal, but when I'm using the cordova serve or where give build the application the scroll bar does not work, I've tried every way, even by setting overflow: auto or overflow: visible does not work ...

can you help me?

Sorry for English.

Comment: Could you post the relevant pieces of code that *might have impact* on the scenario?

Comment: I'm using to pull the pages:
app.config (function ($ routeProvider) {
   routeProvider.when $ ('/' {templateUrl 'pp / inicial.html' reloadOnSearch: false});
   $ routeProvider.when ('/ login', {templateUrl, 'pp / logar.html' reloadOnSearch: false});
});

The "inicial.html" this way:
<div class = "scrollable">
<div class = "scrollable-content">
<h4 class = "corRoxo title" data-ng-init = "carregaRests ()"> Company </ h4>
<div id = "showCitem" class = "clearfix"> </ div>
</ div>
</ div>

In "showCitem" I'm doing a GET request to my remote server

Comment: You can *edit* the question when you have code that you need to add (as you can see - in the comments it gets very messy)

Comment: Post more code for us to help you.